# How to find the row ID from datagridview, given a row value?

Tags: c#, datagridview

Can anyone help me please?

I have to find the row number from 1 selected array which I stored in one separate array and randomly I'm trying to get the row number from datagridview

In other words:
if I know a column value for a given row in a datagridview (e.g. for this row, FirstName == 'Bud'), how can I get the row ID?

Answer (score 18):

You can use LINQ query:

```
        int index = -1;

        DataGridViewRow row = dgv.Rows
            .Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
            .Where(r => r.Cells[columnId].Value.ToString().Equals("Some string"))
            .First();

        index = row.Index;
```

Comment: i dont know the cells id i just stored all the cell in one saprate array, randomly i chosen from that array and i want? in which row its belongs

Comment: Yes, it's right. But you know column, and this query will select first  row which have "Some string" in your column.

Answer (score 1):

There's probably some easier way where you filter it in some way but at the moment I can only think of looping through it.

```
int rowIndex = -1;
foreach(DataGridViewRow row in DataGridView1.Rows)
{
    if(row.Cells(1).Value.ToString().Equals("mystr"))
    {
        rowIndex = row.Index;
        break;
    }
}
// rowIndex is now either the correct index or -1 if not found
```

Answer (score 0):

From: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=610134

> Call the Find method of the
>   BindingSource and it will return the
>   index of the matching row if there is
>   one. If there is, you index the
>   BindingSource to get that row and
>   update the appropriate fields. If
>   there isn't, you call the AddNew
>   method of the BindingSource to create
>   a new row and set the appropriate
>   fields.

Answer (score 0):

```
//If U Have Add CheckBox To Ur Datagridview
int rowIndex = -1;
DataGridViewCheckBoxCell oCell;
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    oCell = row.Cells[0] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell;
    bool bChecked = (null != oCell && null != oCell.Value && true == (bool)oCell.Value);
    if (true == bChecked)
    {
        rowIndex = row.Index;
       //ur code
    }
}
```