# C# How to reposition row selection on DataGridView programmatically

Tags: c#, winforms, linq-to-sql, c#-4.0, datagridview

I am using linq2sql to add a record to my datagridview and refreshing the grid. Right now after refresh it moves the row selection to the top. How would I tell it to highlight the most recent added record?

Not sure if this would help but I have included the code below I am using to find out the pk of the selected row. As what I would like to do is kind of the opposite. Thanks

```
        //get selected row index
        int index = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index;
        //get pk of selected row using index
        string cellValue = dataGridView1["pkColumn", index].Value.ToString();
        //change pk string to int
        int pKey = Int32.Parse(cellValue);
```

Comment: Is the grid databound, or are you inserting rows directly into grid.Rows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know in advance that anytime a new item is added, it should appear at the bottom of the list, you could use:

```
    int index = this.dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1;
    this.dataGridView1.Rows[index].Selected = true;
    this.dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = index;
```

But, if your order the list by other column then you're not going to get the desired results.

I recommend you, is to search for the row-index you need to give the selection to, this could be performed by a function, let's say `int SearchRowIndexForPKValue(int pKey)`, that will perform a look-up within the cell values of the column that contains your PK/ID (`"pkColumn"`) returning the row index. In such way the code above should looks like:

```
    int index =  SearchRowIndexForPKValue(pKey);
    this.dataGridView1.Rows[index].Selected = true;
    this.dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = index;
```

**EDIT:** `int SearchRowIndexForPKValue(int pKey)` is not an existing built-in method of the `DataGridView`. You must declare it and implement it in your code; for the body of the method, you can get the code from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2995970/how-to-find-the-row-id-from-datagridview-given-a-row-value).

Comment: I'm getting SearchRowIndexForPKValue does not exist in the current context

Comment: Sure Adam355, it is not a function of the DataGridView and neither from the .NET framework library, was just a naming example. If you are using LINQ, please look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2995970/how-to-find-the-row-id-from-datagridview-given-a-row-value), there you find the code you need to get the row-index based on a known cell value.