# How to get the corresponding row in datatgridview by the row in datatable?

Tags: c#

In a C# project, I have a datagridview dgv1, and it's datasource is a datatable dt1. For the same data row, the row index in dt1 may be different from the row index in dgv1 after some operation on dgv1, for example sorting. Now, I have one row's index in dt1, and I want to find it's corresponding row in dgv1. Is there any method other than searching data row's value in dgv1?

Comment: To answer your question, @user, no: you want to search the list for the corresponding id.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. I think you can find an answer here to get the dgv row based on the dt row index: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2995970/how-to-find-the-row-id-from-datagridview-given-a-row-value

Comment: Thanks you ! The answer to that question is a LINQ searching method. My datagridview may have a very large number of rows, so the speed may be a problem in my project. That is the reason why I want a method other than searching.