# finding multiple row indexes from a datagridview with linq

Tags: linq, datagridview

the below answer gets me the first row index but there are cases where there are multiple rows with my where clause. how do i get a "record set" where there multiple rows.

```
int index = -1;

DataGridViewRow rowx = 
    dgvMatchErrors.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
    .Where(r => r.Cells[1].Value.ToString().Equals(intErrorRowid.ToString()))
    .First();

index = rowx.Index;
```

[How to find the row ID from datagridview, given a row value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2995970/how-to-find-the-row-id-from-datagridview-given-a-row-value)

Comment: Huh. So you call `First()`, and it returns... the first... item... I wonder how you'd get it not to return the first item?

Comment: i know i am getting only the first. I don't under stand linq. it is only populating index with rowx.index how would i change my search to fill a data set or record set....

Comment: There's code there. It says "FIrst()" at the end. Do you want first? No. So remove the thing that says you want "First".

Answer (score 1):

You can try by removing First() method call in query

```
DataGridViewRow rowx = 
    dgvMatchErrors.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
    .Where(r => r.Cells[1].Value.ToString().Equals(intErrorRowid.ToString())).Select(r=>r);
```

Answer (score 0):

This gives me a list of all my row index based on my where clause.

```
List<DataGridViewRow> rows = 
    dgvMatchErrors.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Where(
           r => r.Cells[1].Value.ToString().Equals(intErrorRowid.ToString())
    ).ToList();
```